# Direction in mutation: add connection operation of NEAT Algorithm

Tags: mutation, neat

I have read the paper of NEAT Algorithm [here](http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/downloads/papers/stanley.ec02.pdf). And want to try it out myself. But I still have one question about the algorithm and that is:

How to determinate the direction of a connection during the add connection mutation operation if 2 hidden nodes are selected?

Let's say I have a network where node 1,2 are input nodes, 3,4,5 are hidden nodes and 6 is the output.

Node 3 and 4 are directly connected with the input 1,2 where 5 currently connected only node 4 and direct it to output node 6.

It is simple to determinate the in and out node of a new connection if one of the nodes is input or output. But if in the case above, the code decided to add a connection between node 3 and node 5. which node should I use as in-node and which as out? or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter. Normally.

The typical solution would be to select first a node from (with some restrictions like: avoid output nodes) then a node to (with some different restrictions, like: avoid input nodes).

Sometimes you will want extra checks. For example, you may want to work with feed-forward-only networks, where connection loops are not allowed. In this case you will need to check that the selected from-to pair of nodes does not create a loop.

However, I strongly recommend that you use and modify an existing implementation of NEAT (check [Colin Green](https://github.com/colgreen?tab=repositories), who takes care of some very high quality NEAR repositories). You will find that NEAT is surprisingly complex to implement if you want all the tricks and good practices.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i have tried to read the existing implementation, it is much more complexer as i thought. and now i think id better just use those library. btw. are there any rules to choice the parameters for NEAT setups? like how the coeffecients for compatibility distance?

Comment: I would start from the defaults... but no, I don't think there is a silver bullet to find the perfect parameters. However, the design of your fitness function is probably a more relevant decision, so try to focus there first.